# Connect timed out issue using proxy in Jsoup

Tags: java, scala, proxy, jsoup

I have encountered a problem for a few days regarding the use of proxy under jsoup.
This error appeared recently, my code was still working a few days ago.

My code extract:

```
val proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, getInetSocketAddress)

Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator())
println("Proxy used : " + proxy)

try {

   var doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreHttpErrors(true)
      .proxy(proxy)
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0")
      .header("Referer", "https://www.google.com/")
      .header("Origin", "https://www.google.com/")
      .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "0")
      .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
      .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document")
      .get()
```

When I use a proxy this error is returned:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
```

My proxy needs an authentication system, which works fine with Selenium.

Here is what I tried:

- Add a .timeout (60000)
- Add a .timeout (0)
- Change the user agent
- Use the .proxy signature (host, port) rather than the Proxy object.
- Search online if an issue has been raised regarding the use of proxies on Jsoup.

I am in scala version 2.12.2 and jsoup 1.14.3

**EDIT**

After some research, I found that the java.net.Proxy doesn't work either while doing this :

```
  val proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, getInetSocketAddress())

Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator())
val openConnection : HttpURLConnection = new URL(imageUrl).openConnection(proxy).asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
  openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/78.0.3904.97 Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36")
  openConnection.setReadTimeout(50000)
  openConnection.setConnectTimeout(50000)
```

My getInetSocketAddress() method returns a new InetSocketAddress.

Answer (score 0):

I have found where the problem comes from.
My proxies were just no longer in working order ... Quite simply.